# Need to instantiate prefab at mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am dragging 2D sprites from the canvas and instantiating a 3D object. But the issue is prefabs are spawning at their default location.[This is the code. Removed all the things I tried for spawning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL0dJ.png)

Comment: instead of a screenshot of the code, can you please add the code? You can get pretty good formatting if you use the specific markup https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instatiate a prefab without specifying the position to instantiate. Try something like this.

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab,eventData.position);
    }
```

Reference:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-position.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything with the objects position so it will spawn at the origin.

Without seeing your project it's hard to guess what you game requires for placing behavior, I'm assuming you have some an environment you want to place it on and that can easily be done with a `Physics.Raycast()`. But if you're not over any environment then you can fire a ray from your mouse position & project it an arbitrary amount forwards from the camera and place the object there for a good effect.

This snippet should be enough for that:

```
public float raycastDistance = 10f;
public float projectDistance = 4f;

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    var spawned = Instantiate(prefab);

    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(eventData.position);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, raycastDistance)
    {
        spawned.transform.position = hit.point;
    }
    else
    {
        spawned.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + (ray * projectDistance);
    }
}
```

If you prefer you can update the position of the spawned object in `OnDrag()` instead of just setting it in `OnDragEnd()` which can look quite nice if you interpolate the position of the object slightly as the mouse moves.